# Error installing eth-brownie in MacOS

Tags: solidity, mac-osx, brownie

I call `pipx install eth-brownie` and get this error:

```
pip failed to build packages:
    bitarray
    cytoolz
    lru-dict

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

I've tried googling to no avail - any advice on how to properly install eth-brownie on Mac?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68329237/installation-errors-with-brownie-python-on-macos

Comment: I tested it on a MacOs with a M1, but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

**First make sure you have Python3 installed, do a quick search for that and come back here once you have installed**

First install Homebrew, if you don't have it installed yet, by typing the following in your terminal:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Then install pipx via Homebrew (that's what you just installed via "curl" command

`brew install pipx`

Once done installing type

```
pipx ensure-path
```

to ensure the path (duh)

Then you need to exit the terminal and open a new terminal window

```
exit
```

Open a new terminal window and run the original scrip you were failing on

```
pipx install eth-brownie
```

If successful, terminal will read:

```
installed package eth-brownie x.x.x, Python x.x.x
These apps are now globally available
- brownie
done!
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a MacOs with M1, I had to perform those steps:

```
STEP1: python -m pip install --user cython
STEP2: python -m pip install --user cytoolz
STEP3: python -m pip install --user eth-brownie
STEP4: python -m pip install --user pipx
STEP5: python -m pipx ensurepath
STEP6: RESTARTED TERMINAL
STEP7: pipx install eth-brownie
```